# Insert images loaded from sqlite into a slider

Tags: java, android, sqlite, slider

Hi guys i'm developing an app which saves images as blob into an sqlite database (i know is a bad pratice to store blobs but i need to do that), my problem is that i don't know how to create a slider showing all images loaded by the database, all results i found on internet are about using static images in drawable res folder, or using url. i followed this guide: http://www.androhub.com/android-image-slider-using-viewpager/ , but cannot solve my problem cause i need to use blobs instead of static images in project, i also tried to convert byte[] to drawable but it does's work

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: And are you asking how to insert or load the images ? You are talking about both but title asks for just loading. Please specify

Comment: `i know is a bad pratice to store blobs but i need to do that` No, you actually don't need to. Store the paths to the images, instead.

Comment: I have to load images from a database, these images i have to load and put in a slider, are images that i store in a sqlite database using a custom camera with opencv, i can't store them normally, the code i'm actually using to try this, is a copy past of the link i gave in the question

Comment: Well, you should actually rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

You say *(i know is a bad pratice to store blobs but i need to do that)*
Always alternative to storing images in a SQLite database as the images cannot be created by SQLite on it's own, it simply doesnt do it.

For Android and using the SDK, images if too big cannot be got easily due to a 2MB limit. So any large image cannot be stored and retrieved. So a camera App will likely go above the limit.

If the image can be save as blob, it can be save to file instead and got.

*i also tried to convert byte[] to drawable but it does's work*

Do this with creteing ImageView from byte[] and use `getDrawable()` from ImageView.